# How do I make a target group listen on a different port than instances being attached via an EC2 autoscaling group in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm setting up an autoscaling group with a launch template in AWS via Terraform.

When I do it like this, the Target Group expects traffic to come in at port 8080 and then it attaches the machines to the Target Group with port 8080.

I would like the Target Group to listen on port 80 but attach instances on port 8080.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "this" { 
  // ... other config
  target_type = "instance"
  port = 8080
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "this" {
  // ... other config
  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.this.arn]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the target group alone. That setting just tells the target group what port it should connect to on the target instances.

If you want to be able to send traffic to this at port 80, you just need to setup the [Load Balancer listener](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener) on port 80. The load balancer listener is the thing an external traffic source interacts with. The load balancer listener is where you set the port that will be exposed externally. The load balancer will accept traffic at the listener port, and then forward that traffic to one of the instances in the target group, on the port configured in the target group.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a load balancer on port 80.

Is this a limitation of EC2 ASG that it's not possible to do what I'm asking though? I know if I attached instances manually I could specify my own port, several even. And I know it works in ECS.

Comment: What limitation are you talking about? The load balancer listens on a specific port, and the traffic is sent to instances on a different port. There are really only 2 ports to configure here. You are trying to configure a different port in the target group like the target group actually listens on a port, but it doesn't, the target group just tells the load balancer what instances to send traffic to, and over what port. Your idea of "I would like the Target Group to listen on port 80 but attach instances on port 8080" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I gave up on wondering how since I don't need to listen on multiple ports anymore.

When you attach an instance through the console without ASG, you can override the default port, and even add multiple ports if you want. Through ASG in Terraform, I don't see a way to do this without creating multiple target groups.

Thanks anyway, I'm good!

Comment: Just for completeness, I would use an attachment to resolve this with just a plain EC2 instead of an ASG https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aaronfeng/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment